# Azure App Service 502 error after login that resolves after page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-appservice

I've got an MVC 5 Web App that just started doing this.

"*502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.*"

Application Insights is telling me this is the problem.

"*The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*"

It's happening on my development site and in production (both are currently in sync). After entering in a username and password and clicking submit, I get this 502 error. This is happening to me and customers. The solution is to refresh the page. This makes the error go away. After refresh, there are no Javascript or other errors on the page.

If I access the application through a Url that doesn't request login (page that displays non-private content) I don't get the error.

Any idea what is happening here? Both App Services are using the same App Service Plan. Both apps are using SNI SSL.

This line of code (ThreadPool) is the problem. Looks like there is a bug in Asp.net 4.7.2.

```
user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { UserManager.Update(user); });
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to this and it seems to work.

```
user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
UserManager.Update(user);
```